# Replacing Column Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I need to clean data in pandas for subsequent analysis but there is a little problem.

On the dataframe.head and in the real dataset the data is to 5 decimal place but when i check indindividually it is somewhat slightly changed. For example 0.49788 becomes 0.49788000000000004

I tried using map and replace to change the values but getting error.

```
data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].map({'0.48246' : 'Female', '-0.48246': 'Male'})
```

will give me Nan in the columns

while age = `{'-0.95197' : '18-24', '-0.07854': '25-34', '0.49788':'35-44', '1.09449':'45-54', '1.82213':'55-64', '2.59171':'65+'}` and `data = data.replace({'Age': age,)` shows errors.

Comment: `round` may help, but thats just an issue with how computers represent floating point numbers.

Comment: and float is not string , you dict key is string

Comment: Try `numpy.isclose()`?